# scala function return type either or

Tags: scala, function, return, return-type

I've a function in `scala` which returns **either** `null` or `List[Double]` or `List[List[List[Double]]]` as per condition. I used the keyword `Any` to define the `return type` and it works for me but if i tried to use the properties of `List` like 'length' on the returned value it gives me error as `value length is not a member of Any`. Currently, i've defined function as :

```
def extract_val(tuple: Tuple3[String,List[Double],List[List[List[Double]]]]): (Any) ={
     /*
        do something here
     */
}
```

I'm trying to find out some way such that i can define either or return type in my function definition as :

```
def extract_val(tuple: Tuple3[String,List[Double],List[List[List[Double]]]]): (either Type A or either Type B) ={
     /*
        if something :
          return null
        elif something:
          return Type A
        elif something 
          return Type B
     */
}
```

I used the `OR operator` as `(Type A || Type B)` but i got some error as `not found type ||`. Any help would be really useful.

Comment: The OR operator for types is called `\/` (resembling the logic symbol for disjunction, ∨) and can be found in the [Scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/) library.

Comment: Might I suggest you return `Option[Either[A,B]]`.  `Option[]` so that you can use `None` instead of `null` and `Either[]` to choose between two unrelated types.

Comment: If you just need the property of a list from the result, you can use the return type: `List[Any]`. It'd handle all three possible return vales, though it's not a good design.

Comment: If possible you should refactor your function so that it's not returning two different things depending on a runtime condition. Return one thing that can be inspected when required to see what data it contains.

Comment: it's really weird to have a function that may return 3 different (and somehow unrelated) types...maybe you should try to refactor

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your return type is always going to be nothing (null) or A or B, then using `Option[Either[A,B]]` is the fastest way to do this.

The main limitation of this solution is that it will be harder to expand it for more types, C, D, etc.

If expandability is what you need, you can implement your own OneOf type. You can do this relatively easy in Scala.

```
sealed trait OneOf[A,B,C]
case class First[A,B,C](a: A) extends OneOf[A,B,C]
case class Second[A,B,C](b: B) extends OneOf[A,B,C]
case class Third[A,B,C](c: C) extends OneOf[A,B,C]
```

Here is a simple (toy) use case:

```
def x(i: Int): OneOf[Int,Boolean,Double] =  i match {
   case 1 => First(10)
   case 2 => Second(true)
   case _ => Third(0.2)
}

scala> x(2)
res1: OneOf[Int,Boolean,Double] = Second(true)

scala> x(1)
res2: OneOf[Int,Boolean,Double] = First(10)

scala> x(2)
res3: OneOf[Int,Boolean,Double] = Second(true)

scala> x(3)
res4: OneOf[Int,Boolean,Double] = Third(0.2)
```

Here is a method that takes a OneOf and handles each option differently.

```
def takeOneOf[A,B,C](x: OneOf[A,B,C]) = x match {
     case First(a) => println(s"A=$a")
     case Second(b) => println(s"B=$b")
     case Third(c) => println(s"C=$c")
}
```

Comment: Nothing is not null.

Comment: I didn't mean the Nothing type in Scala. Nothing as literally you don't have anything to return (or null). Maybe I shouldn't capitalize it.